# Counting the number of elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to count the number of elements which in this case the number of products held by each customer. My attempt for solving this is by counting the number of "li" tag, then accessing "ticket-type". Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?:

```
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@class='ticket-type']"));
int ProdNum = labels.size();
String strI1 = Integer.toString(ProdNum);
System.out.print("Number of products on this card:" + strI1);
// getting the name of the last product
String LastProd = labels.get(labels.size() - 1).getText();
System.out.print("The last ordered product was:" + LastProd);
```

The .html code for this is shown below, where there are 5 products I need to count.

```
<div class="card-details row">
  <div class="pane base4">
  <div class="pane base4">
    <div class="vertical-accordion">
       <ul id="accordion-9" class="accordion">
          <li class="open-li">
             <a class="toggle-link open" href="#">
             <div class="accordion-drop" style="display: block;">
                <ul>
                   <li>
                      <label class="ticket-type">7 day megarider</label>
                      <label class="validity"> (7 day: 04 July to 10 July 2016 ) </label>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                   <li>
                   <li>
                   <li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem with this line `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@class='ticket-type']"));`...

Comment: @Saurabh - I'm not getting the wright count. There should be 5  products as in "li" tag.

Comment: have you tried `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='accordion-drop']/ul/li"));`

Comment: Still not getting the wright count  plus  I need to get the name of the last product.

Comment: I updated the indent of your HTML but that showed that your HTML is not complete. Please update your HTML with valid and relevant HTML.

Comment: @JeffC - I now updated the .html code and this is how it looks if I click on one of the listed elements. In total there are 5 elements I need to count and then grasp the name of the last product. Attempted with the code above but not getting the wright count.

Comment: Your code looks fine given what you have in your question. I know you are expecting 5, what count are you getting? I know your site is https://www.stagecoachbus.com, can you please just link the page so we can look at it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
// Getting total count of all li tag elements
List<WebElement> prodsCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='accordion-drop']/ul/li"));
System.out.println("Total number of products are " + prodsCount.size());

// Getting the last item name
String lastProdName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='accordion-drop']/ul/li[last()]/lable[1]")).getText();
System.out.println("Last product name is " + lastProdName);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Karthik - Still not getting the wright count from the first line.

Comment: how much is the count you are observing?

Comment: Total number of products are : 20 which is wrong but getting the name of the last product correct. I guess the xpath (".//div[@class='accordion-drop']/ul/li") still needs to be corrected.

Comment: Please try to use below xpath: `.//div[@class='card-details row']/div[2]/div/ul`. I hope it should work fine

Comment: Please try to use below xpath: `.//div[@class='card-details row']/div[2]/div/ul/li`. I hope it should work fine

Comment: Thanks Karthik but still not getting the correct count. I'm getting the count of number of 'card-details row',  instead?.

Comment: My bad, please try with this xpath: `.//div[@class='card-details row']/div[2]/div/ul/li/div/ul/li`. If this is not working, can you please provide me the complete html to identify the element uniquely

Comment: The correct answer to all of this is: .//li[@class='open-li']/div/ul/li

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    List<WebElement> numOfLiTag = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//ul[@id='accordion-9']/li/div/ul/li[5]/label[1]"));
    int liTagcount = numOfLiTag.size();
    String abc = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[@id='accordion-9']/li/div/ul/li[5]/label[1]")).getText();
```